# vb6 button click event strange behaviour

Tags: vb6

I have a very large accounting system.  In a user preferences section, the program has begun to act abnormally on my development machine only.  No customers are reporting this, nor can I duplicate it on any of my other computers.  Running Windows 8.1, others are on 7.0.  Not exactly sure when this started happening because it's not the kind of thing one goes into on a regular basis.  The preferences screen consists of a tab control and various standard controls.  At the bottom is Okay, Cancel, and Apply buttons.  All three buttons seem to be acting with the same strange behaviour.  Clicking with a mouse does not generate a click event yet does not hang the system - mouseup follows and you can click it again and see the mousedown and mouseup but no click.  However, since the Okay is defined as Default, pressing enter DOES create the desired click event, and all the code inside that even runs fine.  Cancel and Okay also unload the form, but when clicked, that doesn't happen because none of the code gets executed, yet you can still navigate the screen (move between tabs and controls) but you can't even click the "X" button to close the form at that point.

Also, if you go straight in, and press enter, everything works and the form unloads, but if you do anything before pressing enter (or escape to cancel), like change a tab and/or edit a value, then press enter, the click event again does not run and the system semi-hangs.

I tried turning-off my anti-virus thinking that might have something to do with it, but no-go.  Debugging is frustrating because while I finally got it execute the click event, the stop command inside that event (after debug.print "click") would allow stepping and success if just straight in and enter, but if anything else done as before described would stop at the stop statement (keyboard enter only still no mouse clicks under any scenario) and would do a total lock-out.  In other lockouts where it would let me navigate, almost always selecting a new tab would cause a fatal error and it would force-unload VB for me, otherwise I had to use the task manager.

This is driving me nuts, but I don't know how else to debug it.

Comment: Does your project have anything that can intercept Window messages?

Comment: `but I don't know how else to debug it` -- try Spy++.

Comment: I'll do that, thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to submit an answer yourself if it ever makes any sense.

Comment: @BillHileman Did you get anywhere?

Comment: It's had to take a back-burner since it's only affecting me and I had other things that needed done.  I've downloaded and installed Spy++ but there appears to be quite a learning curve for it.

Comment: I now have a second location where this is happening, and this time it is critical for me.  I can always use another machine, and may have to if I can't figure this out.  I now think this has something to do with Farpoint's VATabPro 2.0 (now Component One) since that's the thing that both forms have in common.  This new place also uses a tab with several panes and it's for magnetic media filing in Payroll.  System does nothing when buttons clicked if other controls edited, allows a tab change if nothing edited, but will throw an exception on tab change after any editing.

Answer (score 2):

The culprit was tv_w32.dll which is Team Viewer.  Turning-off Team Viewer allows my program to run normally.